# What sort of adhesive should I use to run a wire along my car's plastic trim?

Tags: car, adhesive

I replaced the stereo in my car, and the set came with a microphone that I've hung from my rear-view mirror. It has a long, thin wire coated in plastic insulation that needs to run to the head unit. Since I don't want a wire crossing my windshield and dash, I carefully strung it along the inside of the plastic trim that runs along the top and down the side of the windshield, along the inside of the door frame, under the glove compartment, and over to the stereo. I originally affixed the wire with many pieces of double-sided tape, but they've proven ineffective at sticking to the car.

In short, what's the best type of adhesive to use in this situation, and how can I spot-apply it to the wire and my car's trim without making a mess?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the car, you may be able to slide the wire behind the edge of the roof and pillar trim.

If that's not possible, I'd wedge the wire in the corner between the trim and the windshield. Then place a narrow strip of gaffer tape over the wire. Gaffer tape offers good adhesion and is designed to be removable without leaving a residue. You'll have to replace the tape 1-2 times a year because over time it will degrade.

If you want to use glue, the type of glue depends on the trim materials. On many cars, the trim is covered in fabric, which makes it difficult to use glue on and not leave a mess. If the trim is hard plastic, the glue you need depends on the type of plastic. Cyanoacrylate glue often works reasonably well.

Comment: Gaffer/duct tape which left for more than a week will usually leave some residue, and is not a good solution for long time solutions.

Comment: You're correct for duct tape. Gaffer tape is better in this regard (the drawback is that it's much more expensive).